# How to imagesc display the image size to keep the size of the original matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

`data` is a 512-by-512 matrix, visualized by `imagesc`, but the original 512-by-512 size cannot be saved, and the image size can only be saved as 800-by-800 by setting the following.

```
data = rand(512,512);
x = [0 0];
y = [512 512];
figure('position',[200,200,512,512]);
% image(log10(data(1:64,1:64)),'CDataMapping','scaled');
% figure;
imagesc(x,y,log10(data));
axis image;
axis off 
axis equal
axis square
truesize([512 512])
% set(gca,'XTick',[])
% set(gca,'YTick',[])
set (gcf,'Position',[100,100,512,512]);
% truesize(fig,[512 512]);
set(gca,'Position',[0 0 1 1])
axis normal;
saveas(gca,strcat('tumor','.jpg'))
print -djpeg99 'foo.jpg'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. As it stands, it's unclear what your problem is. Can you please [edit] your post for clarity? If I read this correctly: is your problem that your 512-by-512 image is always saved as 800-by-800, rather than in the original size?

Answer (score 0):

[`imwrite`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) uses the data you input as the pixel values to generate an image of the specified size.

This is an example of a 512-by-512 grayscale image:

```
data = rand(512, 512);
imwrite(data, 'foo.jpg');
```

If you want to produce a colour image, you need to input a 3-channel matrix, for example `imwrite(rand(512, 512, 3), 'bar.jpg')`.

The (colour) encoding is otherwise specified in the documentation.

Comment: The numbers in the matrix are too small, and the pictures saved directly are all black, so you need to use the imagesc function to map the values in the matrix to colors.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a statement or a question; do you mean that you are using caxis to change the colour? As per the doc: "If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes that the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values. If the data in A is single, convert A to double before writing to a GIF or TIFF file." Alternatively, you can normalise your matrix before using `imwrite`. Eg `data = (data-min(data(:))/(max(data(:))-min(data(:)))` will change all your data to be between 0 & 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the maximum value of my data is 7.4575533e-04, the minimum value is 0, and there are other values between e-6 and e-7, the data is very dense, the difference is small, normalized Methods such as data = (data-min(data(:))/(max(data(:))-min(data(:))) cannot be distinguished well, and the final image is still completely black.

Comment: In that case, based on the precise nature of your data, I think you will have to look at ways to clean it up/make it easier to modify. Is there a way you can change the data to make it more conducive to being imaged? I believe MATLAB has around E-15 or E-16 precision so E-4 or E-7 should not be that big an issue. Perhaps the data needs to be rescaled/calibrated in some way: but this would depend on exactly what you are trying to do. I think the question as it was originally phrased as been answered, probably best to create a new question.